# QueryDSL: CaseBuilder Ambiguous method call and unexpected AST node

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

My project with springBootVersion 2.5.7, querydsl 5.0.0

have some code:

```
.or(
    Expressions.cases()
            .when(intervalTo.isNotNull())
            .then(
                    enablePath
                            .after(intervalFrom)
                            .and(enablePath.before(intervalTo))
            )
            .otherwise(
                    enablePath.after(intervalFrom)
            )
);
```

1. in **.then** expression i have compile error with Ambiguous method call.
   (Both **then** (Predicate) and then (ComparableExpression<Boolean>))
2. after casting arguments to Predicate i have error:

> <AST>:6:588: unexpected AST node: case antlr.NoViableAltException:
> unexpected AST node: case     at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2174)
> at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2119)
> at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2094)
> at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:832)
> at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:626)

What's my mistake?  thank in advance

Comment: Difficult to say, but you can try `.isTrue()` after the `.cases()...otherwise(..)` because your case returns a boolean expression, but the `.or(..)` expects a Predicate.

Comment: Bad idea, BooleanExpression implement Predicate, this change broke builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my fail, case must return some value:

```
.or(
        Expressions.cases()
                .when(intervalTo.isNotNull())
                .then(
                        Expressions.cases().when(enablePath.after(intervalFrom)
                                        .and(enablePath.before(intervalTo))
                                ).then(1)
                                .otherwise(0)
                )
                .otherwise(
                        Expressions.cases().when(enablePath.after(intervalFrom)).then(1)
                                .otherwise(0)
                ).eq(1)
);
```